# PHP Array_filter on "simple" multi-level array

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

Can I and how can I use PHP's `array_filter` to filter the blank/nulls entries out of the following array structure?

**From:** The array is from a PDO call using Fetch BOTH so the numeric and named values are always equal in this case.

```
Array
(
    [2400] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 7
                    [0] => 7
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 61
                    [0] => 61
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 42
                    [0] => 42
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 
                    [0] => 
                )
        )
)
```

**To:**

```
Array
(
    [2400] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 7
                    [0] => 7
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 61
                    [0] => 61
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 42
                    [0] => 42
                )
        )
)
```

I have tried

- plain old `array_filter`
- `array_filter(array, function($f){ ??? })` and not quite sure where to go from here... I was going to foreach the array to delve into it but how will that affect the entries through `array_filter`? Won't a true/false return bring in the entire [2400] array portion? It just has me confused.

Please suggest improvements to the question

Comment: dod you want remove antry with any null or both?

Comment: any empty or null, the normal criteria that computes to "false"

Comment: you can use `array_map` to browse and remove the blank array.

Comment: @agentprovocateur What if the numeric element is null but the named element isn't, or vice versa?

Comment: Or will they always be equivalent, as in your example? It looks like these arrays come from `mysqli_fetch_array`, which returns both numeric and named elements for each selected column, and they're the same.

Comment: @Barmar the numeric and named part will always be equal in this case because its from PDO and its fetching BOTH.

Comment: Why don't you just change the SQL query so it doesn't return null values in the first place?

Comment: @Barmar Its a query in a function that i use in multiple places and i need it to be able to return empty values from that function.. i could make another function though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can not be done using only [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function because sometimes you need to modify array elements but the `array_filter` function allows only to decide if the element should be excluded or not.

For example in the main array element with index 2400 should be included in the result set but it's content should be modified.

I wrote a simple function to do this, hope it might help. Well, you might use this for inspiration. And it was interesting challenge for me as well.

Below is my function with couple tests.

```
<?php

function deepFilter(array $array)
{
    // Formally this is not need because if array is empty then $filteredArray will also be empty
    // but it simplifies the algorithm
    if (empty($array)) {
        return [];
    }

    $filteredArray = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && !empty($value)) {
            $value = deepFilter($value);
        }
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $filteredArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $filteredArray;
}

$testArray1 = [
    2400 => [
        0 => [
            'value' => 7,
            0 => 7,
        ],
        1 => [
            'value' => 61,
            0 => 61,
        ],
        2 => [
            'value' => 42,
            0 => 42,
        ],
        3 => [
            'value' => null,
            0 => null,
        ]
    ]
];

$testArray2 = [
    2400 => [
        0 => [
            'value' => 7,
            0 => 7,
        ],
        1 => [
            'value' => 61,
            0 => 61,
        ],
        2 => [
            'value' => 42,
            0 => 42,
        ],
        3 => null
    ],
    3243 => [
        0 => [
            'value' => 7,
            0 => null,
        ],
        1 => [
            'value' => null,
            0 => 61,
        ],
        2 => [
            'value' => 42,
            0 => 42,
        ],
        3 => null
    ]
];
var_export(deepFilter($testArray1));
var_export(deepFilter($testArray2));
```

The idea is very simple.

1. Take an array and check elements one by one.
2. If element is an array, apply the function for that element and check the result. We can remove everything from child array and in this case we should not add it to results. Else if child has something remaining after cleanup include 'cleaned child' in our result set.
3. If our element is not an array then include it only if it's not empty.

Please let me know if you find any mistakes or if it works for you or not.

Comment: yes that was the problem I was running into while trying out the suggestions in the other answers.
It would give me blank arrays instead of excluding that key completely.
I did create my own function to loop through the array and check elements one by one and that worked exactly as I needed it.
I believe you answered my question the best, "will array_filter work for this"

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_filter` and test the `value` element (or the `0` element, since they're equivalent).

```
$array[2400] = array_filter($array[2400], function($element) {
    return $element['value'];
});
```

To do it for all elements of the outer array, use a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($array as &$subarray) {
    $subarray = array_filter($subarray, function($element) {
        return $element['value'];
    });
}
```

or `array_map`:

```
$array = array_map(function($subarray) {
    return array_filter($subarray, function($element) {
        return $element['value'];
    });
}, $array);
```

Comment: hmm.. the "2400" key is variable and can change.

Comment: So loop over all elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

If the array structure stays the same then this should work:

```
foreach ($array as &$innerArray) {
    $innerArray = array_filter($innerArray, function($arr) { 
        return (!empty($arr[0]));
    });
}
unset($innerArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concisely filter the subset data by making iterated calls of `array_filter()` via `array_map()`.  You can avoid writing a custom function for `array_filter()` [by calling the native function `array_sum()` (or `array_product()`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72060362/2943403) -- this yields the correct truthy/falsey result because any data set with nulls will be calculated as `0`, and everything else with be non-zero ("truthy").

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FYuht))

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn($row) => array_filter($row, 'array_sum'), $array)
);
```