# Remove/Filter rows from array which contain a zero

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, zero, array-filter

I have an array of non-empty arrays which contain non-negative integers and I need to remove all rows/subarrays which contain at least one zero.

I know I can use a `foreach()` or `array_filter()` to make iterated calls of `in_array()`, but is there a more elegant/concise approach -- perhaps a functional approach without an anonymous callback?

```
foreach ($array as $k => $row) {
    if (in_array(0, $row)) {
        unset($array[$k]);
    }
}
```

Or

```
array_filter(
    $array,
    function($row) {
        return !in_array(0, $row);
    }
)
```

Sample array:

```
$array = [
    'one' => [20,0,40,0,60],
    'two' => [50],
    'three' => [0, 0, 0, 0],
    'four' => [10, 5],
    'five' => [0],
];
```

Desired output:

```
['two' => [50], 'four' => [10, 5]]
```

Comment: Isn't the *but is there a more elegant approach* a subjective measure?

Comment: Are you worried that this question is Opinion-based? Do you want me to change it to "more concise"?  I feel pretty confident that Stack Overflow has other open questions that use this phrasing -- though I cannot provide any hyperlinks off the top of my head.

Comment: Perhaps just the terminology - but I'm not sure what is a better wording (damn, just caused a recursive loop about more elegant/better....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all honesty, I think that PHP7.4's arrow function syntax makes the `array_filter()` call reasonably concise.

```
array_filter($array, fn($row) => !in_array(0, $row))
```

Additionally, iterated calls of `!in_array()` with a `true` third parameter can distinguish between different types and ensure that only integer-typed zeros are targeted. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mfuDp))

```
array_filter($array, fn($row) => !in_array(0, $row, true))
```

That said, because you have non-empty subarrays, you can use `array_product` as the callback name.  By multiplying all values in a respective row together, any row containing a zero will result in `0`. Since `0` is a falsey value, `array_filter()` will exclude the row from the result array.  This approach will work even if there are floats or negative numbers in the subarrays.  Be aware that `array_product()` will not remove empty rows/subarrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/A80Sl))

```
var_export(
    array_filter($array, 'array_product')
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'two' => 
  array (
    0 => 50,
  ),
  'four' => 
  array (
    0 => 10,
    1 => 5,
  ),
)
```

---

For the slightly altered behavior of only keeping rows that contain at least one non-zero value, `array_sum` can be used in the same fashion. This approach will still work with empty subarrays or subarrays containing floats, but should not be trusted if a mix of negative and positive values in a respective subarray is possible. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4odnq))

```
var_export(
    array_filter($array, 'array_sum')
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'one' => 
  array (
    0 => 20,
    1 => 0,
    2 => 40,
    3 => 0,
    4 => 60,
  ),
  'two' => 
  array (
    0 => 50,
  ),
  'four' => 
  array (
    0 => 10,
    1 => 5,
  ),
)
```